# How can can I get the entered value that matches blockRegexes in PyInputPlus.inputStr() function

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, validation, input

I have a simple multiplication quiz from the [automate book](https://automatetheboringstuff.com) and I want to expand on it.
My goal is to collect the incorrect answers and display them at the end of the game.
However, the way the code checks for the correct answer is by blocking everything except the correct answer using the `blockRegexes` parameter.
I've tried checking for the validation exception but that doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
import pyinputplus as p
import random, time

numberOfQuestions = 10
correctAnswers = 0
incorrectAnswers = []

#def blockRegRaiseExcep(text):
    # because in a regular inputStr it won't raise an exception if I match the blocked regex.
for questionNumber in range(numberOfQuestions):

    # Pick two random numbers:
    num1 = random.randint(0,9)
    num2 = random.randint(0,9)

    prompt = f'#{questionNumber}: {num1} x {num2} = '

    try:
        # Right answers are handled by allowRegexes.
        # Wrong answers are handled by blockRegexes, with a custom message.
        inp = p.inputStr(prompt,allowRegexes=[f'^{num1 * num2}$'], # allow only the right number! great.
                         blockRegexes=[('.*','Incorrect!')], # we are blocking everything, basically, love it!
                         timeout=8, limit=3)

    except p.TimeoutException:
        print(f'Out of time!\nCorrect answer is {num1 * num2}')
        
    except p.RetryLimitException:
        print(f'Out of tries!\nCorrect answer is {num1 * num2}')
    else:
        # This block runs if no exceptions were raised by the try block.
        print('Correct!')
        correctAnswers += 1

    time.sleep(1) # Brief pause to let the user read the result.

print(f'Score: {correctAnswers} / {numberOfQuestions}')
```

Answer (score 0):

There are actually different ways you can achieve what you want.

1. There is an optional parameter `applyFunc` which is common to all `input*()` functions, see [documentation](https://pyinputplus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#common-input-parameters) or call `help(pyip.parameters)`:

   > `applyFunc` (Callable, None): An optional function that is passed the user's input, and returns the new value to use as the input.

   You can use this function to save the input and pass it on unaltered to the validation. If you only want to store the input in case it is incorrect, you need to check the condition again within this function.

   Example:

   ```
   import pyinputplus as p
   import re

   # hardcoded values for example
   incorrectAnswers = []
   questionNumber = 1
   num1 = 2
   num2 = 3
   prompt = f'#{questionNumber}: {num1} x {num2} = '

   def checkAndSaveInput(n):
       if not (re.match(f'^{num1 * num2}$',n)):
           incorrectAnswers.append(n)
       return(n)

   inp = p.inputStr(prompt,
       allowRegexes=[f'^{num1 * num2}$'],
       blockRegexes=[('.*','Incorrect!')],
       applyFunc=checkAndSaveInput)

   print("Your wrong answers were:")
   for a in incorrectAnswers:
       print(f'  {a}')
   ```

   Execution:

   ```
   #1: 2 x 3 = six
   Incorrect!
   #1: 2 x 3 = 4
   Incorrect!
   #1: 2 x 3 = 5
   Incorrect!
   #1: 2 x 3 = 6
   Your wrong answers were:
     six
     4
     5
   ```
2. Since with the approach above, you need to check the condition again anyway, you could also directly write a [custom `inputCustom()` function](https://pyinputplus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#pyinputplus.inputCustom). The following example uses the regexes in `allowRegexes` and `blockRegexes` only to validate that an `int` is entered and the actual result checking is not done with a regex but instead with simple math. The difference to the approach above is that the values are actually only handed to the checking function *after* it is made sure that they match the pattern in `allowRegexes`.

   ```
   import pyinputplus as p

   # hardcoded values for example
   incorrectAnswers = []
   questionNumber = 1
   num1 = 2
   num2 = 3
   prompt = f'#{questionNumber}: {num1} x {num2} = '

   def checkAndSaveInput(n):
       if((num1 * num2) != int(n)):
           incorrectAnswers.append(n)
           raise Exception('Incorrect.')
       else:
           print('Correct!')

   inp = p.inputCustom(checkAndSaveInput,
       prompt=prompt,
       allowRegexes=[r'^\d+$'],
       blockRegexes=[('.*','Please enter a valid number!')])

   print("Your wrong answers were:")
   for a in incorrectAnswers:
       print(f'  {a}')
   ```

   Execution:

   ```
   #1: 2 x 3 = six
   Please enter a valid number!
   #1: 2 x 3 = 4
   Incorrect.
   #1: 2 x 3 = 5
   Incorrect.
   #1: 2 x 3 = 6
   Correct!
   Your wrong answers were:
     4
     5
   ```